# Is it possible Script out sql query to .sql file using ssis?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

IS is possible to script out each stored procedure to .sql file using ssis ?

I have a query as

```
SELECT  definition
FROM    sys.sql_modules procs
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON procs.object_id = o.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE   o.[type] = 'P'
```

I am looking  each row as each .sql file on folder
I have Image example as

Note : I dont have access to `exec xp_cmdshell`

Thanks,

Comment: You could use a C# script task and then use [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure.Script()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedure.script.aspx) to script the stored procedures in your database.  However, I'd probably use PowerShell to do it.  Much simpler than writing a script task in SSIS.

Comment: And if C# scares you, you can use the Smo method that @BaconBits is suggesting with powershell. That's how I'd do it!

Comment: Yes that SQL just returns a rowset that you can dump to a text file. But you'd probably need to manually add stuff like "GO' to it. Why don't you try dumping what you have to a text file and post any issues you have